# How to get Actual path of redirected path?

Tags: c++, winapi, 32bit-64bit

A 32-bit process running on 64-bit would get *generalized* path to a redirected path, due to file-redirection. A call to `GetCurrentDirectory`, for example, if process is running from `\Windows\SysWOW64` would get result: `Windows\System32`.

Though, it is very much possible to determine if 32-bit process is running on 64-bit host machine. I am looking for a solution to give me correct/actual path. Something like ResolveWOWPathToActual path, that would give `\Windows\SysWOW64` for a path `\Windows\System32`.

EDIT:

```
WCHAR szCurFolder[MAX_PATH];

PVOID dummy;
Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(&dummy);

GetCurrentDirectoryW(MAX_PATH, szCurFolder);

printf("Current Dir: %S\n", szCurFolder);
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365743(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Disable the redirection, do your work, enable them again.

Comment: Already tried that. Doesn't work. Updating question to add code.

Comment: You should check if the `Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection` failed or succeed.

Comment: Anything else, Abhineet?

Comment: Is `Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection` suceeding?

Comment: Yes, it succeeds... it seems that this is returning the "wrong" path.. at least for my Win7SP1...

Comment: Interestingly, `FindFirstFile(".", &fd)` is also returning "system32" instead of "syswow64"...

Comment: `GetCurrentDirectory` has no interaction with the file system redirector. It's just a textual property of the process. The current directory really is `System32` in this case. Redirection kicks when you try to resolve the directory to a file system object.

Comment: Yes, FindFirstFile and other functions gives 'System32', not 'SysWOW64'.

Comment: Yes, `GetCurrentDirectory` doesn't do much. I have experimented that command `explorer .` from 32-bit cmd.exe would launch \Windows\System32 in explorer, and not `Windows\SysWOW64'.

Comment: And it also seems that `GetFullPathName(".")` is using the "wrong" current directory ;(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API function [`GetFinalPathNameByHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364962.aspx) might serve your needs. You will have to open the file or directory to obtain a handle to it. Pass that handle to `GetFinalPathNameByHandle` and it will give you the true path of the file. There is no need to disable the file system redirector.

I suppose the only possible downside is that this does require you to supply a handle rather than a path.

Comment: This also leads to problems... it returns `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` if FsRedir is *enabled* and it returns `C:\Windows\System32` if FsRedit is *disabled* ;)  I assumed it should always return the "correct" one...

Comment: @JochenKalmbach That's to be expected. If file system redirection is disabled then `C:\Windows\System32` really means `C:\Windows\System32`. If you want to use a term like "correct" you need to be very precise about what that actually means.

Comment: It serves the purpose. Excellent. Just need to strip off "\\?\" from beginning.