# Why do I get a different SHA1 hash between Powershell and 32bit-Python on a system DLL?

Tags: python, powershell, x86, 64-bit

I'm trying to calculate SHA1 hash values in Python against binary files for later comparison. To make sure things are working, I used several methods to check the validity of my result. And, I'm glad I did. Powershell and Python return different values. 7zip's SHA1 function agrees with Powershell's results and Microsoft's FCIV agrees with Python's results.

Python:

```
import hashlib
with open("C:\\Windows\\system32\\wbem\\wmiutils.dll", "rb") as f:
     print(hashlib.sha1(f.read()).hexdigest())
```

Powershell:

```
PS C:\> Get-FileHash C:\Windows\System32\wbem\wmiutils.dll -Algorithm SHA1
```

Results:

```
Python: d25f5b57d3265843ed3a0e7b6681462e048b29a9
Powershell: B8C757BA70F6B145AD191A1B09C225FBA2BD55FB
```

> EDIT: 32-bit Python and 64-bit Powershell against a system32 dll. That
>   was the problem. I have some homework to do but basically, 32-bit and
>   64-bit applications receive a different file and thus, different hash
>   results. I launched 64-bit python and ran the exact same code against
>   the dll and as a 64-bit powershell process. Received consistent
>   results when running both processes as 32-bit.
>
> EDIT2: Found this resource that explains things a bit. At least it
>   helped me understand what's going on:
>   https://www.sepago.com/blog/2008/04/20/windows-x64-all-the-same-yet-very-different-part-7-file-system-and-registry

Comment: I don't remember exactly how Windows does this, but could it be  that Python is 32bit process and you are getting the 32bit version of wmiutils.dll?   Test it on another file which is not a dll and not in system32.

Comment: Nailed it! Launched a 32bit Powershell window and it returned: D25F5B57D3265843ED3A0E7B6681462E048B29A9

Comment: This could also be due to a difference in how python/FCIV and 7zip/Powershell handle string to bit conversion: see [Is SHA-1 Hash Always the Same](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18290/is-sha-1-hash-always-the-same)

Comment: Well, so now I have another question: Why do I get a different SHA1 hash between **GNU/sha1sum** and Python on binary files?

Comment: Now I want to know if there is a way to determine the actual file being returned by the file system redirector. This feels like the beginning of a rabbit hole...

Comment: most likely there is no sane way of doing it from Python.   From a native app you can do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23650436/how-to-get-actual-path-of-redirected-path You can also just assume that if you are running 32bit on a 64bit OS things will get crazy like that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is happening because you are running a 32bit version of Python and accessing a system dll -- Windows magically redirects you to the 32bit version of the dll, while PowerShell is running as a 64bit process and sees the 64bit version of the DLLs.

I am not sure if I am glad I know this or saddened by it.

Comment: Seeing as this is specifically for hashing of dll's, your insight was super helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Got here because I found copies of files that were binary the same and the MD5 was the same but the SHA1 is different! These are JPG image files, and I am using the same exe to generate the hashes....so there ought to be no redirection going on at all...still, nice to know we are no alone in the universe :P